# Changing JPEG's colorspace from sRGB to YCbCr

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I have been trying to convert a JPEG image in the sRGB colorspace to one in the YCbCr colorspace using the following command:

```
mogrify -colorspace YCbCr -depth 24 -size 150x193 image.jpeg
```

However, the colorspace does not seem to change after executing it. What could be going wrong with this command?

The output of identify -verbose on this image is the following:

```
Image:
Filename: image.jpeg
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 150x193+0+0
Resolution: 300x300
Print size: 0.5x0.643333
Units: PixelsPerInch
Colorspace: sRGB
Type: TrueColor
Base type: Undefined
Endianness: Undefined
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
  Pixels: 28950
  Red:
    min: 130  (0.509804)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 251.923 (0.987932)
    standard deviation: 8.05183 (0.0315758)
    kurtosis: 36.456
    skewness: -5.49367
    entropy: 0.442837
  Green:
    min: 118  (0.462745)
    max: 204 (0.8)
    mean: 159.128 (0.62403)
    standard deviation: 9.36402 (0.0367216)
    kurtosis: -0.462288
    skewness: 0.200554
    entropy: 0.78474
  Blue:
    min: 0  (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 189.949 (0.7449)
    standard deviation: 94.4421 (0.370361)
    kurtosis: -0.32277
    skewness: -1.18683
    entropy: 0.705024
Image statistics:
  Overall:
    min: 0  (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 200.333 (0.78562)
    standard deviation: 37.286 (0.14622)
    kurtosis: 1.44763
    skewness: -1.33571
    entropy: 0.6442
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
  red primary: (0.64,0.33)
  green primary: (0.3,0.6)
  blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
  white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 150x193+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Quality: 90
Orientation: Undefined
Properties:
  date:create: 2022-03-16T23:34:06+00:00
  date:modify: 2022-03-16T23:34:06+00:00
  jpeg:colorspace: 2
  jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
  signature: b2382be8d45c90dbdad1b663e64566a32876f1ec0f8f10a74f2f4632932e4c4d
Artifacts:
  filename: image.jpeg
  verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 9058B
Number pixels: 28950
Pixels per second: 27.0576MB
User time: 0.010u
Elapsed time: 0:01.001
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org
```

I am on ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 running on Ubuntu 21.10.

Thank you in advance,
Joshua

Comment: I am trying to convert to YCbCr, not CMYK and the reason for the conversion is not really printing but compatibility with some old piece of software which I need to ensure

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely get what you're trying to say as I only have a very superficial knowledge of image processing. But if I get it correctly I somehow need to "uncompress" the JPEG and then change the colorspace to YCbCr before finally compressing it again? If so, how would I go about this "uncompressing"?

Comment: I've tried converting to a linear colorspace by doing
./magick image.jpeg -colorspace RGB -colorspace YCbCr image_new.jpeg
But image_new.jpeg is still reported as sRGB.

Comment: I have also noticed that I can convert the colorspace to YCbCr if I first convert to TIFF and don't convert back to JPEG. But when I want to convert this YCbCr coded TIFF to JPEG with ImageMagick the JPEG is again coded in sRGB.

Comment: Have you found any solution ? If so, I am interested in it.